# How to clear thread pool's threadlocal content in Java 8?

Tags: java

I am using this code to clear thread pools threadlocal content in Java 8 to avoid other thread read wrong threadlocal data:

```
package com.sportswin.soa.robot.common;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MapUtils;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Slf4j
public class ThreadLocalAwareThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public ThreadLocalAwareThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
                                      BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        try {
            if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(SessionUtil.getThreadLocal())) {
                SessionUtil.getThreadLocal().clear();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("clear thread info error", e);
        } finally {
            super.afterExecute(r, t);
        }
    }
}
```

but the program never run into `afterExecute` this code. Am I missing something? This is the `getThreadLocal` code:

```
 public static Map<String, Object> getThreadLocal() {
        return threadLocal.get();
    }
```

Comment: what does `SessionUtil.getThreadLocal()` do?

Comment: "To properly nest multiple overridings, subclasses should generally invoke super.afterExecute at the beginning of this method." this is from the docs, where you call super.afterExecute doesn't have to impact, but... doesn't hurt to give a chance